# Make Sonar override "don't declare 'throws Exception'" only in unit test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube

I agree that it's generally a bad idea to declare "throws Exception" in normal Java code.

However, I think it is a good idea to do this in unit tests.  It simplifies the test method, but still results in any unexpected exceptions causing the test to fail.

I'd like to see if it's practical or possible to make Sonar only report this issue for classes not ending in "Test".  I'd rather not add overrides in the code, I'd prefer to make this happen entirely in the Sonar configuration, or in the properties sent through sonar-runner.

Can anyone see a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Since SonarQube 4.0 (or if you have an older version, using the Switch Off Violations plugin), you can [define a pattern](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) to ignore this rule on classes ending in `Test`:

- Connect to SonarQube with a global administrator account
- Go to: Administration > Configuration > General Settings > Analysis Scope
- Find section: Issues > Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria
- Add an entry with:

  - Rule Key Pattern: `squid:S00112`
  - File Path Pattern: `**/*Test.java`

Please also note that recent versions of SonarJava (at least since 3.1) only apply a specific set of rules to test classes.